# using multiple variables in regex pattern

Tags: regex, string, variables

I have defined a number of variables that represent Japanese strings.
I want to create a regex pattern that will look for any of these string patterns, but not
in any particular order. So, for example,
`kata_a = 'エイ'`
`kata_b = 'ビー'`
... (also defined for c - z)

In the interest of readability, I want to be able to search for kata_a or kata_b or kata_c etc..
Sorry, I'm very new to regex, but I don't see how to create a pattern that captures each of these sequences separately or in combination. I tried `(kata_a | kata_b)` as an attempt to try just the first two but got a syntax error. Also tried `((kata_a) | (kata_b))`. That too didn't work.

Incidentally, I'm working in Python 3.3 with the regex module, so I'm using:
`pattern = regex.compile(??????)`

Thanks.

Comment: Your katakana strings are ... weird. Sure, the English letter *a* is pronounced "ei" in isolation, but ... What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

First, whitespace is significant in a regex, so if you put a space inside your regex, it will try to match a space in the text you're using it on.

Second, Python doesn't do variable interpolation automatically. But you can do something like

```
words = ['エイ', 'ビー']  # add more words ad libitum
pattern = re.compile("(" + "|".join(words) + ")")
```

The parentheses aren't strictly required here, but they will become necessary if anything else is added to the regex, so I'm putting them there for safety.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are strings. You cannot "logically or" strings, but you can concatenate them with the string `'|'` in between to form a new regular expression which matches either string.

```
pattern = regex.compile(kata_a + '|' + kata_b)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the pattern to be compiled must be a string unto itself, though the string can contain | inside it. Thanks for explaining why it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer is less elegant than the ones above, but I did get this to work.

kata_a = 'エイ'
kata_b  = 'ビー'
(etc.)

args = (kata_a, kata_b, ... (etc.))

kata_letters = '''{0}|{1} ...'''.format(*args) 
[triple quotes needed because it runs multiple lines]

And finally,

matches = regex.findall(kata_letters, search_target)

I think simply joining a list as described above is a lot more straightforward, however. Thanks for all your input.